# How to fix this python problem with regex?

Tags: python, regex

Consider the Python program below.

```
import re
  words = input("Say something!\n")
  p = re.compile("my name is (.*)", re.IGNORECASE)
  matches = p.search(words)
  if matches:
    print(f"Hey, {matches[1]}.")
  else:
    print("Hey, you.")
```

Given input like My name is Earl, this program politely outputs Hey, Earl. Given
input like My name is Earl Hickey, though, this program outputs Hey, Earl Hickey,
which feels a bit formal. Propose how to modify the argument to re.compile in
such a way (without hardcoding Earl) that this program would instead output Hey,
Earl in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `r"my name is (\w+)"`. `\w+` restricts the capture group to a sequence of word characters, so we'll [make the assumption](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) that everything up until the end of the word is the first name.

```
import re

words = input("Say something!\n")
matches = re.search(r"my name is (\w+)", words, re.I)

if matches:
    print(f"Hey, {matches[1]}.")
else:
    print("Hey, you.")
```